# HTTP Triggered Azure function to upload file

Tags: c#, reactjs, file-upload, azure-functions

I am looking for an example of an HTTP Triggered Azure function that uploads[image] a file in C#.

The front end is made in React:

```
const onSave = async () => {
    console.log(fileToUpload)
    if (Object.keys(fileToUpload).length === 0) {
        alert("Errore, selezionare un file per l'upload!");
    }
    else {
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: { fileToUpload }
        };
        fetch('http://localhost:7071/api/upload', requestOptions)
            .then(response => console.log(response)
            );
```

In the attached image you can find the toUpload object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to send your file to Azure function in your react application, you can create `FormData` and save file in the form data then send the form data to azure function. The detailed steps are as below

- **Server**

1. Configure CORS. Please add the following code in your `local.settings.json`.

```
"Host": {
    "CORS": "*"
  }
```

2. Code

```
 [FunctionName("Http")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
        {

            var files = req.Form.Files;

            foreach (var file in files) {
                log.LogInformation("The file name is : " + file.FileName);
            
            }

            return new OkObjectResult("OK");

        }
```

- Client

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css';\
import fetch from 'node-fetch'

class App extends Component {
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import fetch from 'node-fetch'

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedFile: null
    }

  }
 // get file
  onChangeHandler = event => {
    console.log(event.target.files[0])
    this.setState({
      selectedFile: event.target.files[0],
      loaded: 0,
    })

  }
 //send file
  onClickHandler = async () => {
    const data = new FormData()
    data.append('file', this.state.selectedFile)
    await fetch("http://localhost:7071/api/Http", { method: 'post', body: data })
      .then(res => console.log(res))
      .catch(error => console.error(error))



  }
  render() {
    return (

      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <div className="form-group files">
              <label>Upload Your File </label>
              <input type="file" name="file" onChange={this.onChangeHandler} />
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-success btn-block" onClick={this.onClickHandler}>Upload</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just one more question. Unfortunately in the ReadableStream object I am unable to get the file content. I only get the file size. Any hint on how to achieve that?

Comment: const onChangeHandler = event => {
        console.log(event.target.files[0])
        setFileToUpload(
           event.target.files[0]
        )
    }
    const onSave = async () => {
           console.log(fileToUpload)
       
        
            const data = new FormData();
            data.append('file', fileToUpload)
            await fetch("http://localhost:7071/api/upload", { method: 'post', body: data })
              .then(res => console.log(res))
              .catch(error => console.error(error))
}

Comment: <div {...getRootProps()} id="center-dropzone">
                    <input {...getInputProps()} type="file" name="file" onChange={onChangeHandler}/>
                    <div style={{
                        width: "250px", backgroundColor: isDragActive ? "#a0cfcd" : "#E0E0E0", borderRadius: "25px"
                    }}>
                        <center><BsCloudUpload size="80px" style={{ marginTop: "20px", marginBottom: "20px" }} />

                        </center>

                    </div>

Comment: const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive } = useDropzone({ / onDrop / });

Comment: @OuterSpace Where do you want to read fie content? Client or server?

Comment: @OuterSpace Please try to use the following code `var files = req.Form.Files;
            foreach (var file in files) {
                log.LogInformation("The file name is : " + file.FileName);
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream())) {
                    var content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                    log.LogInformation("the file content is \n" + content);
                }
            
            }`